# 500 Error with CraftQL

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftql

I’ve installed CraftQL and can successfully query from the Craft admin interface but when I hit the endpoint using Axios I get a 500 server error. I've checked that my endpoint matches what's set in CraftQL's settings. Any idea why this is failing?

Here’s my Axios code:

```
axios
  .create({
    baseURL: "/api",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer R0Fq9-AAAAA-7hXQrigZqiFfq9BevLGdHrZWn6FNVaABCJsq-CZQuGxqklmntl`,
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }
  })
  .post("", {
    query: `
    {
    entries(section:[testSection], limit:5) {
      ...on TestSection {
        title
        url
      }
    }
    }
`,
    variables: ""
  })
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: The 500 error message should either be logged in Craft's log files or your web server's error logs (depending on where it originated). I'd start by checking those.